# android notification id should be different each time or not

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using notification in my app. I just wanna make sure that one thing, if i have only one type of notification and should I use the same id each time or what happens if i change id each time generate a notification?

```
mgrNotificationManager.notify(id, note);
```

Answer (score 5):

The [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) says:

> If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

So if you change the id every time, the system will handle that as a second notification.